# Get and set properties in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Problem with the next decision...
I have an object User, which contains only 1 property:

```
function User(fullName) {
  this.fullName = fullName;
}
```

the first- and lastname are only devided by space.
I need to do firstName and lastName properties available by (get), and it has to be possible to change that propirties by (set).
For example:

```
var vasya = new User("Vasya Popkin");

// reading firstName/lastName
alert( vasya.firstName ); // Vasya
alert( vasya.lastName ); // Popkin

// writing в lastName
vasya.lastName = 'Black';

alert( vasya.fullName ); // Vasya Black
```

fullName has to keep as a property.

My code:

```js
function User(fullName) {
    this.fullName = fullName;
    Object.defineProperty(this, "firstName", {
        get: function () {
            return this.fullName.split(' ').slice(0, 1);
        },
        set: function (value) {
            fullName.split(' ').splice(0, 1, value).join(' ');
        }
    });
    Object.defineProperty(this, "lastName", {
        get: function () {
            return this.fullName.split(' ').slice(1);
        },
        set: function (value) {
            this.fullName.split(' ').splice(1, 1, value).join(' ');
        }
    });
}

var vasya = new User("Vasya Popkin");

console.log(vasya.fullName);
console.log(vasya.lastName);
console.log(vasya.firstName);
vasya.lastName = 'Black';
vasya.firstName = 'Jack';
console.log(vasya.fullName);
console.log(vasya.firstName);
console.log(vasya.lastName);
```

But i have some trouble which i cant understand. The code is not working. I cant get new fullName. I think i dont have enough understanding of arrays methods.
Please help me to fix this code. Thank you!

Comment: *"the first- and lastname are only devided by space"* This assumption is invalid. A **huge** range of names cannot be divided into "first" and "last" based on the location of a space and the assumption that what comes before it is a "first name" and what comes after it is a "last name."

Comment: You are not saving fullName in set functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Preface: Please see [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57116443/get-and-set-properties-in-javascript/57116567#comment100751622_57116443).

The problems with the code are:

1. That you're using `slice` and returning the result (an array), but really what you want to do is access the entry in the array at index `0` (first name) or `1` (last name).
2. You're using the return value of `splice`, which is an array of the **deleted** items, not the remaining ones.
3. You're not setting the `fullName` property in your setter. (Assigning to entries in the array resulting from `split` doesn't change the string that `split` created the array from.)

I wouldn't try to do it with a one-liner (it's possible, it's just harder to understand, debug, and maintain). See comments on `firstName` (`lastName` is just the same sort of thing, but handling the case where there is no space):

```js
function User(fullName) {
    this.fullName = fullName;
    Object.defineProperty(this, "firstName", {
        get: function () {
            // Return just the part at index 0 of the array after split
            return this.fullName.split(' ')[0];
        },
        set: function (value) {
            // Split into parts
            var parts = this.fullName.split(' ');
            // Set the first part
            parts[0] = value;
            // Join back into a string
            this.fullName = parts.join(' ');
        }
    });
    Object.defineProperty(this, "lastName", {
        get: function () {
            return this.fullName.split(' ')[1] || "";
        },
        set: function (value) {
            var parts = this.fullName.split(' ');
            parts[1] = value;
            this.fullName = parts.join(' ');
        }
    });
}

var vasya = new User("Vasya Popkin");

console.log(vasya.fullName);
console.log(vasya.lastName);
console.log(vasya.firstName);
vasya.lastName = 'Black';
vasya.firstName = 'Jack';
console.log(vasya.fullName);
console.log(vasya.firstName);
console.log(vasya.lastName);
```

Answer (score 0):

- You are not setting the `fullName` property in `set`
- [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) returns the deleted items from the array. So, using `join` on what the `splice` returns won't work;

So, you need to change the `set` logic to couple more steps like this:

```js
function User(fullName) {
  this.fullName = fullName;
  Object.defineProperty(this, "firstName", {
    get: function() {
      return this.fullName.split(' ')[0];
    },
    set: function(value) {
      var names = this.fullName.split(' '); // array of 2 names
      names.splice(0, 1, value); // update the array
      this.fullName = names.join(' '); // set full name
    }
  });
  Object.defineProperty(this, "lastName", {
    get: function() {
      return this.fullName.split(' ')[1];
    },
    set: function(value) {
      var names = this.fullName.split(' ')
      names.splice(1, 1, value)
      this.fullName = names.join(' ');
    }
  });
}

var vasya = new User("Vasya Popkin");

console.log(vasya.fullName);
console.log(vasya.lastName);
console.log(vasya.firstName);

vasya.lastName = 'Black';
vasya.firstName = 'Jack';

console.log(vasya.fullName);
console.log(vasya.firstName);
console.log(vasya.lastName);
```